# Laravel - Cannot view images saved from Storage path in shared hosting

Tags: laravel, symlink

I cannot see images saved from storage folder in shared hosting.

Blade code

```
<embed src="{{Storage::disk('local')->url(''.$applications->id_img) }}"
```

symlink:

```
/home/username/folder/storage/app/public/ to /home/username/public_html/storage
```

Comment: have you run `php artisan storage:link` command ?

Comment: Hi Akhtar, thanks for your reply. I tried creating symlink using php method and it was successful. I tried php artisan storage:link in routing method but returning symlink() cannot be found. Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: You can place a simple route and write `Artisan::call('storage:link');` on live server. Then hit the url to run the command on live server. also tell me what's your path saved in database ?

Comment: Hi Sir, I tried this just now,        ```     Route::get('/foo', function () {
                  Artisan::call('storage:link');
              }); ``` and it returns "symlink(): No such file or directory"

Comment: can you show what path is saved in your database of the image ?

Comment: Hi Sir, here is one example : public/gI1yP9SyxiwxGdC9Yect0n7z2lZgyxFGNZtnYm8u.jpeg

Comment: okay try this code in your view `<img src="{{ storage_path().'/app/'.$applications->id_img }}" />`

Comment: Hi Akhtar, still the image doesn't show. :(

Comment: Okay can you tell me, are your images in storage or public or in both places ?

Comment: Yes it is tore in storage/app/public and I can see it too in my symlink public_html/storage

Comment: Okay try one thing, in your hosting you will see permissions give storage folder 777 permission, just for testing and see if it works by using this code `<img src="{{ storage_path().'/app/'.$applications->id_img }}" />` and also tell me how have you deployed your project live ?

Comment: Yes Sir it is already in 777 permission as checked.

Comment: are you receiving image path in this variable `$applications->id_img` from database ? first `dd($applications->id_img);` in your controller and check it.

Comment: No, it looks like this : $applications = application::all()->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('user.application.show',compact('applications'));

Comment: what is your field name in database where you are storing the image path ? and this `$applications = application::all()->where('id', $id)->first();` should be like this `$applications = application::where('id', $id)->first();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215521/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-imurangel).

Comment: Field name is : image , and im storing it like this :             if ($request->hasFile('fcode_img')){
                $fcode_img =  $request->fcode_img->store('public');
                }

Answer (score 0):

---

When you need to move that image to public/ path in your controller

```
public function store(){
$imageName = time().'.'.request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
request()->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName); 
}
```

then use

```
  <embed src="{{ asset("images/$imageName")}}">
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, Thank for you reply. May I know what can happen when I transfer it to public/ path? Will this work in shared hosting? Thanks!

Comment: you mean that if you upload this project to host ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a day trying with the help of Sir Ahktar and Hassan, the piece of code of code helps me https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/2365. `$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
//use this if you are using a subdomain
return dirname(getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.preg_replace('#^https?://#', '',env('APP_URL')));
// use this if you are using public_html
// return dirname(getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public_html');
}); then run storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

To view images stored in Storage Path in shared hosting:

Create the route below in your web.php file

```
Route::get('/create-symlink', function (){
    symlink(storage_path('/app/public'), public_path('storage'));
    echo "Symlink Created. Thanks";
});
```

Then run it in browser "https://yourdomainhere.com/create-symlink"

This should resolved it.